# Getting property names of a class using expressions, static methods, and a base object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a common problem, that I am trying to get round in a specific way.

Basically with Winforms, I am trying to set the "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" of controls in a form. You would normally set it like so:

```
this.testCombobox.DisplayMember = "PropertyOne";
this.testCombobox.ValueMember = "PropertyTwo";
```

I want to rewrite this as follows:

```
this.testCombobox.DisplayMember = ClassOne.GetPropertyName(c => c.PropertyOne);
this.testCombobox.ValueMember = ClassOne.GetPropertyName(c => c.PropertyTwo);
```

(NOTE: the 2 method calls need to be static, to save creating objects here)

All of my classes that I am trying to do this, inherit from a base class "BaseObject", so I have added a method to it as follows:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> action) where T : class
{
    MemberExpression expression = action.Body as MemberExpression;
    return expression.Member.Name;
}
```

However, in order to use this, I need to write the following code instead:

```
this.testCombobox.DisplayMember = BaseObject.GetPropertyName((ClassOne c) => c.PropertyOne);
```

My question is, how would I rewrite the method `BaseObject.GetPropertyName` to achieve what I want? I feel I am very close but cannot think how to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current GetPropertyName method leaves open the generic T. Hence, the compiler cannot resolve it compile-time since you do not specify it when you use the method.

However, if you make your base class generic, AND specify the T in the derived class, AND specify to use the method of the derived class (and not the base class), then it works.

Like this:

```
public class BaseClass<T> {
    public static string GetPropertyName<P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> action) {
        MemberExpression expression = action.Body as MemberExpression;
        return expression.Member.Name;
    }
}

public class ClassOne : BaseClass<ClassOne> {
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
}
public static class Test {
    public static void test() {
        var displayMember = ClassOne.GetPropertyName(x => x.PropertyOne);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it. Thanks Maarten!

Answer (score 4):

I created a Helper class to extract Proprty Name

```
  public static class PropertySupport
  {       
    public static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
      if (propertyExpression == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
      }

      var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
      if (memberExpression == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalide Expression", "propertyExpression");
      }             
      return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
  }
```

And you can use it as Follows :

```
PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(() => DateTime.Now)
```

it will return "Now"

**EDIT**

Here is a test console app:

```
  public static class PropertySupport
  {       
    public static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
      if (propertyExpression == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
      }

      var memberExpression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
      if (memberExpression == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("", "propertyExpression");
      }      
      return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
  }
  public class MyClass
  {
    public MyClass PropertyOne { get; set; }
  }
  class Program
  {    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {      
      Console.WriteLine(PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(() => new MyClass().PropertyOne));
      Console.ReadKey();
    }   
  }
```

Comment: And how would you call this method to get the property name of an actual class? I have tried with what you have here, and cannot get it to work.

Comment: A simple call like PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(() => YouClassInstance.Property). I use it in all my projects and it work perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Ah ok, it was the newing up of a new object that I never tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following in generic helper:

```
    public static class GenericHelper<TEntity> {

        public static string GetPropertyName<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertyExpression) {

            return propertyExpression.GetPropertyName();
        }
    }
```

and the following in Extensions for common usage:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions {

    public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<TEntity, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> source) {

        //TODO: check TEntity, if needed. Now it's ignored

        var member = source.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (member == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.", source));
        }

        var propertyInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

        if (propertyInfo == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.", source));
        }

        return propertyInfo;
    }

    public static string GetPropertyName<TEntity, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> source) {

        return source.GetProperty().Name;
    }
}
```